# Cannot declare web3 object in JavaScript

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, infura

When I try to declare a web3 object It's always `undefined`.

I'm writting in JavaScript and using Infura as my provider for the ETH mainnet. I also tried with a local blockchain instead of Infura, but it also didn't work. I'm new to blockchain development and I'm kinda stuck on this. I know it must be something very small I'm missing, maybe I forgot to install something. I've also spent quite some time researching my problem, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/web3.js/master/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
        const rpcURL = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/INFURA_PROJECT_ID";
        const address = 'MY_WALLET_ADDRESS';

        const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcURL));

        web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, wei) => {
            myBalance = web3.utils.fromWei(wei, 'ether')
            console.log(myBalance)
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post the errors you get in console?

Comment: `web3 is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two problems here. First, you can't directly include raw files hosted on GitHub because of their CORB policies, but there's a workaround for this, just follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github) steps. What you'll get in the end is this URL:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js

Then, it's better to wait for the document to be fully loaded, because it might be that script will execute before Web3 is actually included. 
You can use `window.onload` with pure Javascript, `$(document).ready()` with jQuery.

So the final script ends up being:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            const rpcURL = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/INFURA_PROJECT_ID";
            const address = 'MY_WALLET_ADDRESS';

            const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcURL));

            web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, wei) => {
                myBalance = web3.utils.fromWei(wei, 'ether')
                console.log(myBalance)
            })
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. This did indeed fix my problem with the web3 object being `undefined` and I marked you answer as correct. But I would still like to point one thing out.

The line `myBalance = web3.utils.fromWei(wei, 'ether')` will throw an error telling you that web3.utils is not imported. You can look at the below code for the fix.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            const rpcURL = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/MY_INFURA_PROJECT_ID";
            const address = 'MY_WALLET_ADDRESS';

            const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcURL));

            web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, wei) => {
                var balanceA = wei;
                balanceB = web3.toDecimal(balanceA);
                var balanceC = web3.fromWei(balanceB, 'ether');

                console.log("ding");

                console.log(balanceA);
                console.log(balanceB);
                console.log(balanceC);

                console.log("dong");
            })
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because you're using `web3.fromWei` while the correct method is `web3.utils.fromWei`. Try this out and let me know whether it works.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The above code does work. `web3.utils.fromWei()` doesn't work whereas `web3.fromWei()` does work. The problem is fixed now :), thank you again for you help.

Comment: That's because this CDN hosts version 0.20.6, I thought it was the latest. My bad.